# Make overlay text of a different color, or use background to make text partly other color

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I would like to make the text white when it overlays some image, or to use image for changing some elements that interacts with it. In my example you can see the text is always black, but i wish to make it white (or other specific color) in part of overlaying image.

UPD: Only part that overlays image should change color. Other part must remain its original color. Also, image may be round or any random shape. Please, have a look at example
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFnYw.png)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.image {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg");
  width: 35vw;
  height: 35vw;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 7vw;
  right: 12vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <span class="text">Some cool text</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've tried to use mix-blend-mode, but I can't figure out how to make text exactly white or other specific color.

Answer (score 0):

The `mix-blend-mode` property allows you to blend the colors of the text and the background image in different ways in CSS. To make the text white, you can use the difference value for `mix-blend-mode` and set the color of the text to white using the `color` property. Here's an example to see how it works:

**CSS Code:**

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 7vw;
  right: 12vw;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

This will make the text white when it overlays the blue image in your example. You can replace white with any other specific color you want.

Comment: Well, text becomes painted yellow where it overcrosses image and below and it is absolutely white, and became invisible because of white background on other side. That's not a solution, I've tried to play with it also as well )

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .image {
        background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg');
        width: 35vw;
        height: 35vw;
      }

      .text {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 7vw;
        right: 12vw;
        color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
        mix-blend-mode: screen;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <span class="text">Some cool text</span>
      </div>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can check this, if you try to use a gray color it will look like this. you can play with the gray colour and see what fits you.